# How to use CFMutableDictionaryRef with ARC

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting, core-foundation

Is this how you are supposed to use a CFMutableDictionaryRef with ARC?

```
CFMutableDictionaryRef myDict = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
NSString *key = @"someKey";
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1];
//ARC doesn't handle retains with CF objects so I have to specify CFBridgingRetain when setting the value
CFDictionarySetValue(myDict, (__bridge void *)key, CFBridgingRetain(value));
id dictValue = (id)CFDictionaryGetValue(myDict, (__bridge void *)key);
//the value is removed but not released in any way so I have to call CFBridgingRelease next
CFDictionaryRemoveValue(myDict, (__bridge void *)key);
CFBridgingRelease(dictValue);//no leak
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Don't use `CFBridgingRetain` and `CFBridgingRelease` here at all.  Also, you need to use `__bridge` when casting the result of `CFDictionaryGetValue`.

```
CFMutableDictionaryRef myDict = CFDictionaryCreateMutable(NULL, 0, &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
NSString *key = @"someKey";
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1];
CFDictionarySetValue(myDict, (__bridge void *)key, (__bridge void *)value);

id dictValue = (__bridge id)CFDictionaryGetValue(myDict, (__bridge void *)key);
CFDictionaryRemoveValue(myDict, (__bridge void *)key);
```

There is no need for `CFBridgingRetain` because the dictionary will retain the value anyway.  And if you don't call `CFBridgingRetain`, you don't need to balance it with a release later.

Anyway, this is all much simpler if you just create an `NSMutableDictionary` and then, if you need a `CFMutableDictionary`, cast it:

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSString *key = @"someKey";
NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt: 1];
[myDict setObject:value forKey:key];

CFMutableDictionaryRef myCFDict = CFBridgingRetain(myDict);
// use myCFDict here
CFRelease(myCFDict);
```

Note that a `CFBridgingRetain` can be balanced by a `CFRelease`; you don't have to use `CFBridgingRelease` unless you need the `id` that it returns.  Similarly, you can balance a `CFRetain` with a `CFBridgingRelease`.

Comment: I shouldn't use CFBridgingRetain because the CFDict will retain for me?